# my aboutus.html is not connected to the aboutus.css through the link?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, styles

for some reason, I tried to connect my aboutus.html with the main.css through the link but it just couldn't be connected. is there something that I messed up at. Please help me figure it out.

//HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="text/css" href="main.css">
```

//CSS

```
body {
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
    }

#aboutus h2 {
margin-bottom: 25px;
               }

.img-wrap {
width: 100%;
       }

.img-wrap  img {
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999999;
                }
```

Comment: Can you also show us the structure of your directory? And one more thing, is `href="main.css"` suppose to be a typo? As you say you are linking `aboutus.css` but instead used `main.css`

Comment: I meant to say main.css but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You have taken href="text/css" href="main.css" two time remove href="text/css" and check.

Answer (score 1):

Please include your CSS Using following Tag, may be this work for you
  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">`

Answer (score 0):

You have taken href="text/css" href="main.css" two time remove href="text/css" and check.